# Error in calling Rest Services "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: c#, .net, rest, service

hello Friends, 
              I'm calling 1 rest services from windows 8 Store app, that service is hosted on wamp server that return JSon data.When I enter that URL from my browser it display proper JSON data,but whenever I try to call through code using HttpClient, it throws an exception   " `An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 192.168.2.161:8080` "

> Stack Trace :   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

```
           try
        {
            HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync("http://192.168.2.161:8080/Demo/?q=lgwebservice/Demo-Services");

            string res = response.Content.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}
```

Comment: 192.168.2.161 looks like a looks like local address is that by intention?

Comment: yes... Actually 2.161 system is on LAN having all the installation of wamp server and services are hosted on that system only..

Comment: Does it respond on ping?

Comment: Yupe..  even if I call that URL from browser, it does return data properly, it just not working through code

Comment: Does it change anything if you do:
            var uri = new Uri(@"http://192.168.2.161:8080/legaljini/?q=lgwebservice/legal-contract");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(uri);

Comment: Have you any authentication system on your web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I was recently having this problem so I thought having an answer posted would be helpful.

You've probably noticed that you can hit an external IP, but because you are working on a local network, you need to enable this "capability" in the app manifest.

- Open Package.appxmanifest from the solution explorer
- Select the Capabilities tab.
- check "Private Networks (Client & Server)

You should be good to go at this point.