# Calling REST service via HttpClient from ASP.net 4 Web API 2 project results in exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

**Current Situation:** I have created an ASP.net project (web project) using the WebAPI 2 template. One of the HTTPGET method now tries to make a request to another REST API using the following code.

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    var uri = @"http://api.../...";

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // <- exception here

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return content;
}
```

At the line, marked with the comment, the following `HttpRequestException` with the message "Unable to connect to the remote server" (inner exception) is thrown.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=mscorlib
  ...
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
       InnerException: 
            ErrorCode=10060
            HResult=-2147467259
            Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ...
            NativeErrorCode=10060
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
            InnerException:
```

**What I tried so far:**

1. I used the exact same URI (via copy & paste) in the browser and the JSON with some data is returned.
2. Before creating the WebAPI2 project I played around with the RC candidate of ASP.net 5. I created a project based on the ASP.net 5 template "Web API". There I have the exact same code and it is working fine.

**Assumption:** My assumption is that the config in the ASP.net 4 Web API 2 template has some config that prevents from getting a response. I found some similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634142/error-in-calling-rest-services-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server) on SO where it seems that some private networking was disabled.

**Question:** What does prevent the response from being received when using HttpClient in a ASP.net 4 Web API 2 based project?

Comment: can you try with other get methods like `GetStringAsync(String)`?

Comment: exactly the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out what the root cause is. The short answer is that the ASP.net 5 template used a proxy, probably one that is configured via Windows group policies, while the ASP.net 4 template directly connected to the other REST service. But because this is prohibited by some firewall it didn't work.

**Long answer:** In order to check the network traffic of both templates (ASP.net 4 and 5) I used Process Monitor from sysinternals tools. I set a filter to IISExpress.exe and dnx.exe.

For the ASP.net 4 template this looked as follows.

[image]

There are only two entries where you can see that IISExpress directly connects to the REST service. In case of ASP.net 5 there are a lot more entries because instead of a direct connection it uses a proxy. I actually assumed that this is a proxy because of its host name. One point to note here is that instead of IISExpress.exe, dnx.exe is building up the connection.

[image]

In order to let IISExpress use a proxy for the ASP.net 4 template I added the following lines into the projects `web.config`. I used the hostname and port as shown in Process Monitor.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True"
           proxyaddress="http://proxy.<hostname>:<port>"
           bypassonlocal="True"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

So my assumption is that somewhere in Windows this proxy is configured, probably via group policies(?). Firefox, dnx.exe, and others are using this configuration. But IISExpress ignores this and therefore does not receive an answer from the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening may be he has not allowed Public to use, there may be some specific domains allowed. As what it seems to me.

You can read this article for better understanding : 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api